# Is there a good way to remove the "next" and "prev" links from Laravel Paginate API, other than removing it in the frontend?

Tags: laravel, vue-component, laravel-10

My response looks like this:

```json
"links": {
    "first": "http:\/\/localhost:8000\/api\/tasks?page=1",
    "last": "http:\/\/localhost:8000\/api\/tasks?page=200",
    "prev": null,
    "next": "http:\/\/localhost:8000\/api\/tasks?page=2"
},
"meta": {
    "current_page": 1,
    "from": 1,
    "last_page": 200,
    "links": [
        {
            "url": null,
            "label": "&laquo; Previous",
            "active": false
        },
        {
            "url": "http:\/\/localhost:8000\/api\/tasks?page=1",
            "label": "1",
            "active": true
        },
        {
            "url": "http:\/\/localhost:8000\/api\/tasks?page=2",
            "label": "2",
            "active": false
        },
        {
            "url": "http:\/\/localhost:8000\/api\/tasks?page=3",
            "label": "3",
            "active": false
        },
        {
            "url": "http:\/\/localhost:8000\/api\/tasks?page=4",
            "label": "4",
            "active": false
        },
        {
            "url": "http:\/\/localhost:8000\/api\/tasks?page=5",
            "label": "5",
            "active": false
        },
        {
            "url": "http:\/\/localhost:8000\/api\/tasks?page=6",
            "label": "6",
            "active": false
        },
        {
            "url": "http:\/\/localhost:8000\/api\/tasks?page=7",
            "label": "7",
            "active": false
        },
        {
            "url": "http:\/\/localhost:8000\/api\/tasks?page=8",
            "label": "8",
            "active": false
        },
        {
            "url": "http:\/\/localhost:8000\/api\/tasks?page=9",
            "label": "9",
            "active": false
        },
        {
            "url": "http:\/\/localhost:8000\/api\/tasks?page=10",
            "label": "10",
            "active": false
        },
        {
            "url": null,
            "label": "...",
            "active": false
        },
        {
            "url": "http:\/\/localhost:8000\/api\/tasks?page=199",
            "label": "199",
            "active": false
        },
        {
            "url": "http:\/\/localhost:8000\/api\/tasks?page=200",
            "label": "200",
            "active": false
        },
        {
            "url": "http:\/\/localhost:8000\/api\/tasks?page=2",
            "label": "Next &raquo;",
            "active": false
        }
    ],
    "path": "http:\/\/localhost:8000\/api\/tasks",
    "per_page": 2,
    "to": 2,
    "total": 400
}
```

I can make use of the first `links`, and just use those, but I still want to have the numbered links, as Laravel gives them back, meaning: goes from 1 to 10, has a "..." link, then some from the last links.

Is there a way to do that on the API? I don't want to splice the first and last links all the time on the frontend and so-far, that's the only suggested solution I've found.

Or if there's a way to just return the numbered links as I mentioned above, that would be amazing too!

Edit:
I tried the boot method suggestion, this is how it looks:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\JsonResource;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Register any application services.
     */
    public function register(): void
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     */
    public function boot(): void
    {
        JsonResource::macro('paginationInformation', function ($request, $paginated, $default) {
            // change it however you want...
            unset($default['links']['prev']);
            unset($default['links']['next']);

            return $default;
        });
    }
}
```

and then my resource:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Resources;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\JsonResource;

class TaskResource extends JsonResource
{
    /**
     * Transform the resource into an array.
     *
     * @return array<string, mixed>
     */
    public function toArray(Request $request): array
    {
        return [ ... returning my stuff ... ]
```

But it still includes the prev-next links, so they're not unset.
I also tried modifying it to `$default['meta']['links']['prev']` and `next`, but that didn't solve it either.

Comment: Have a look at the documentation for this: https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/pagination#customizing-the-pagination-view. You can use one of the pre-built paginators, or you can publish and customize them (i.e. publish the one with `First, Prev, 1 ... 10, Next, Last` and remove what you don't actually need. (Sidenote I'm not sure if this would work when using Laravel as an API, but there might be something in those docs that could help)

Comment: Are you using API resources for this?

Comment: Yes, I'm using API Resources for this. I also tried the above mentioned option but it didn't work with it. 

I've looped throught the docs, but couldn't find anything, this problem has been bothering me for the past few months (since then I kept splicing the unwanted links, but now it's just a nightmare).

Comment: in the `JsonResource::macro` method, did you check if `$default` is an actual nested array and `$default['links']['prev']` has an actual value? Since `$default['links']['prev']` may or may not exist. Idk since I dont really use macro. Just a thought.

Comment: use resource collection to modify the json response or a custom paginator. Good example: https://github.com/laravel/framework/discussions/41513

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The final solution turned out to use "DataTables". That, and a "custom" combination of returning the data and the total. With that, DataTables handles the pagination completely, while the laravel API returns only what is requested.

Something similar:

https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/ajax

Answer (score 0):

Using API resources you can modify this creating a macro on `JsonResource` in your AppServiceProvider's boot method

```php
use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\JsonResource;

JsonResource::macro('paginationInformation', function ($request, $paginated, $default) {
    // change it however you want...
    array_shift($default['meta']['links']); 
    array_pop($default['meta']['links']); 

    return $default;
});
```

Had to sourcedive to find this
https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/0c574d42e9c7d82a0bd304a5cb2ce031a914bfa6/src/Illuminate/Http/Resources/Json/PaginatedResourceResponse.php#L53

Comment: I added a response to this suggestion. TL;DR: it didn't solve the problem, those links are still *set*.

Comment: I don't think i understand how the result of the pagination should look like, if you could give an example that would help. With this macro you should be able to change it anyway you like.  maybe this is what you want instead?

            array_shift($default['meta']['links']);
            array_pop($default['meta']['links']);